# Autoreleased NSMutableArray not populated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, return, autorelease

I want to populate an array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [self methodThatReturnsAnArray];
```

In the "methodThatReturnsAnArray"-method I create an array like this:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayInMethod = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

When I'm finished populating "arrayInMethod" I'm returning the array and in order to prevent a memory leak I'm using:

```
return [arrayInMethod autorelease];
```

However the "array"-variable is never populated. When removing the "autorelease" it works fine though. What should I do in order to make sure that the returned object i released?

**EDIT**

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)buildInstants:(NSArray *)huntsArray {

    NSMutableArray *goGetObjects = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    for (int i = 0; i < [huntsArray count]; i++) {

        NSDictionary *huntDict = [huntsArray objectAtIndex:i];

        PHGoGet *goGet = [[PHGoGet alloc] init];

        goGet.title = [huntDict objectForKey:@"title"];
        goGet.description = [huntDict objectForKey:@"description"];
        goGet.start = [huntDict objectForKey:@"start"];
        goGet.end = [huntDict objectForKey:@"end"];
        goGet.ident = [huntDict objectForKey:@"id"];

        if ((CFNullRef)[huntDict objectForKey:@"image_url"] != kCFNull) {

            goGet.imageURL = [huntDict objectForKey:@"image_url"];

        } else {

            goGet.imageURL = nil;
        }

        if ((CFNullRef)[huntDict objectForKey:@"icon_url"] != kCFNull) {

            goGet.iconURL = [huntDict objectForKey:@"icon_url"];

        } else {

            goGet.iconURL = nil;
        }

        goGet.longitude = [huntDict objectForKey:@"lng"];
        goGet.latitude = [huntDict objectForKey:@"lat"];
        goGet.companyIdent = [huntDict objectForKey:@"company_id"];

        [goGetObjects insertObject:goGet atIndex:i];
        [goGet release];
    }

    return [[goGetObjects copy] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Removing the `autorelease` shouldn't make any difference at all, at least not immediately. Can you post the rest of the code in the `methodThatReturnsAnArray`?

Comment: Where are you checking that array is not populated? Just after the return or some time later(may be from a button handler)?

Comment: @kubi Now I have added some code

Comment: `-copy` method returns an NSArray but the method definition has it defined as NSMutableArray but if you wanted to return a NSMutableArray object, you should just change the last statement to `return goGetObjects;`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. What error/bad behavior are you seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the convienence method for `NSMutableArray`... change:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayInMethod = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

To...

```
NSMutableArray *arrayInMethod = [NSMutableArray array];
```

`array` will return an autoreleased object.

Comment: They're actually called 'factory' methods.

Comment: I've always heard them called convenience methods. :)

Comment: Technically, they are factory methods, but no one in the ObjC world calls 'em that.

Comment: GoF Factory Method: Define an interface for creating an object, but let subclasses decide which class to instantiate. Factory Method lets a class defer instantiation to subclasses...  I don't think a method that simply allocs, inits, autoreleases fits that definition.  Is there another type of factory method that does?

Comment: I have tried this but with no desirable result. Something with the autorelease is not working, built in or not.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend you not to return a NSMutableArray from any method. It's better to use NSArray for that to avoid some very difficult to debug problems. My proposition is:

You declare the mutable array and populate it:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayInMethod = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Then you return an autoreleased copy:

```
return [[arrayInMethod copy] autorelease];
```

And finally, when you take the returned array, you make it mutable again (only if you need to change it):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[self methodThatReturnsAnArray] mutableCopy];
```

When you're done with the array, you release it:

```
[array release];
```

Comment: I added the code from the method with your changes in the question

Comment: Erik, it really works. You can search in Stackoverflow and you'll find many other ways of solving it, that was only my personal solution. Please expose the problems you're experiencing so we can help you!